# JSON undefined or null

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax

Im trying to access a API and heres the tree i want to access:

```
{"19777621": [{
   "queue": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
   "name": "Vladimir's Maulers",
   "entries": [{
      "leaguePoints": 0,
      "isFreshBlood": false,
      "isHotStreak": true,
      "division": "I",
      "isInactive": false,
      "isVeteran": false,
      "losses": 34,
      "playerOrTeamName": "Razdiel",
      "playerOrTeamId": "19777621",
      "wins": 36
   }],
   "tier": "PLATINUM"
}]}
```

I managed to do a lot of examples but this is the one i really cant figure out how it works, im sure i can the response body but if i try to do something it comes as undefined blank or Object.

```
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/json2.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/json_parse.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$.ajax({
url: 'https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v2.5/league/by-summoner/19777621/entry?api_key=b05c2777-462b-4bcc-ac2a-a3223bb74876',
type: 'GET',
dataType: 'json',
data: {

},
success: function (json) {
document.write("The Result Is:")

    JSON_Encoded = json;
    JSON_Decoded = JSON.stringify(json);
    document.write(JSON_Decoded[19777621].name[0])
    document.write(JSON_Decoded[19777621].entries.losses[0])

},
error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
alert("error getting Summoner data!");
}
});

</script>
```

I know im doing something wrong i just wanted to know what

Comment: Have you tried using a tool like Postman? It allows you to send POST and GET requests to URL's, and shows you the response. It's really useful for testing API's, most likely your API is giving you an error that isn't in a JSON format. EDIT: Or just use Parse instead of stringify, thanks other comments can't believe I missed that.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` turns an object into a, well, **JSON string**. The reverse is `JSON.parse`! And you probably don't need either, since the response will probably already be decoded.

Comment: when you're accessing your object too you'd want 

JSON_Decoded[19777621][0].name

Comment: i did all the changes you guys said and it still doesnt give me anything at all: JSON_Decoded = JSON.parse(json);
    document.write(JSON_Decoded[19777621][0].name)

Comment: If you look up what `dataType: 'json'` implies, then you will know why it doesn't work.

Comment: still doesnt work at all =( i tried all the changes you guys gave me http://pastie.org/10737234 i will look into that Felix Kling

Comment: General hint: learn to debug using `console.log` (or better yet the built-in debugger with breakpoints, but let's start slow). Put `console.log(json);`, `console.log(JSON_Decoded[19777621])` and so on in useful spots in your code and watch your browser's Javascript console. Instead of poking into the dark, **see** what you have and how it needs to be transformed/accessed/handled.

Comment: thanks deceze i should stop a bit and learn how to debug my own stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write it in this way ...

```
$.ajax({
url: 'https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v2.5/league/by-summoner/19777621/entry?api_key=b05c2777-462b-4bcc-ac2a-a3223bb74876',
type: 'GET',
dataType: 'json',
data: {

},
success: function (json){
  document.write("The Result Is:")

  //JSON_Encoded = json;
  //JSON_Decoded = JSON.stringify(json);   
  document.write(json['19777621'][0].name)
  document.write(json['19777621'][0].entries[0].losses)

},
error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
alert("error getting Summoner data!");
}
});
```